# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un diccionario asociativo en Bash?

Tags: array, bash, variables, shell

Estoy deseando hacer un programa para reproducir música y me gustaría que al mismo tiempo o tal vez al final de la reproducción aparezca el nombre de la canción...

Ejemplo:

```
*se ejecuta el "mpv"
*termina la canción
Esto ha sido Master of Puppets - Metallica
$
```

Mi código (algo primitivo puesto que soy nuevo):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Vídeos que se van a reproducir
items=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y") 

#Asignar un valor a cada vídeo
size=${#items[@]}
randomindex=$(($RANDOM % $size))

#Reproducir el vídeo a partir de un valor aleatorio por medio de "MPV"
mpv ${items[$randomindex]}
```

Me gustaría que dependiendo del valor que se le de a "items" pueda utilizar el comando echo para indicar que canción fué la que se reprodujo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Se me ocurre utilizar el "if", solo que no sé como usarlo jeje... Algo como:

```
if 
  $items=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y
  echo "Esto fue The Look-Metronomy"
```

Comment: ¿Dònde está contenido el título de la canción? Porque la clave aquí está en extraerlo

Comment: Ese es el problema... si se pudiera hacer algo estilo if

Comment: if items=1 echo "Back in black" por poner un ejemplo

Comment: ¿es decir que proporcionas tú la lista y el mapeo? 1 - bla, 2 - ble, etc. Pues entonces es un caso para usar `case` o incluso un array que lo contenga todo.

Comment: Exacto! Alguna idea de como lo podría hacer (con un ejemplo si se puede)?

Comment: A pesar de mis reticencias a votar, voto positivo solo por escuchar ese "Master of puppets" de Metallica; también + a la respuesta de @fedorqui, siempre aprendo algo

Comment: Jajaja gracias amigo. Que puedo decir, solo me gusta la buena música xD

Comment: @GuardabosqueS siempre es un placer leerte. Que votes, parece un lujo... mójate más!

Comment: Un placer @fedorqui ; que sepas que me costó darle al botón... Aunque luego tuve cierta sensación placentera :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas probablemente se resuelve con un hash, definido así en Bash 4:

```
declare -A animals
animals=( ["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
```

Y de esta manera cada índice se asocia a un valor. En tu caso podría ser del tipo:

```
declare -A canciones
canciones=( ["Hell Bells"]="https://www.youtube.com/bla" ["La Macarena"]="https://www.youtube.com/ble" )
```

Sin embargo tu solución debe además incluir la selección aleatoria de un elemento. Como hacerlo con un hash es un poco tedioso, ¿qué tal si en la lista actual guardas cada elemento como tupla URL-nombre?

```
items=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs|La Macarena" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8|Paquito el Chocolatero")
```

Y luego guardas los valores así:

```
url=$(cut -d'|' -f1 <<< ${items[randomindex]})
titulo=$(cut -d'|' -f2 <<< ${items[randomindex]})
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que adaptando un poco el código como dices funciona bien!

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, bienvenido al mundo de `bash`, es el arma más apasionante que he usado en mi trayectoria como desarrollador. Segundo, sin duda @fedorqui dio una respuesta muy valiosa y precisa porque da cuenta de la versatilidad de usos que tienen los arrays asociativos en bash.

Yo trataré de aportar otra solución que no tiene que ver con la pregunta del array asociativo (a riesgo de que me regañen), eso ya lo contestó @fedorqui con el uso de `declare -A array=( [clave]="valor" )`.

Tú tratas de utilizar un array, te sugiero el uso de un archivo con un formato específico para que uses como una pequeña base de datos. Por ejemplo, un archivo que se llame `videos.txt` cuyo contenido sea algo con la siguiente estructura.

```
titulo1|video1
titulo2|video2
```

Por ejemplo:

```
Gilles Deleuze - ¿Qué es el acto de creación? (completo) - Subtitulado al Español|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXOzcexu7Ks&t=699s
What are societies of control?|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_i8_WuyqAY
Manuel DeLanda - The Philosophy of Gilles Deleuze. 2007 4/5|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By-SPWKK0pg
Sociología - Theodor Adorno|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YGnPgtWhsw&t=290s
PHILOSOPHY - Michel Foucault|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBJTeNTZtGU
```

Entonces tienes tu script de bash tendría que lucir de la siguiente manera.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare _videos_db="./videos.txt"  # Base de datos sencilla.

declare _total_videos="$( 
    cut -d " " -f 1 <<< "$(wc -l $_videos_db)" 
)"  # Obtenemos el total de los videos con wc.
declare _random_choice="$(( RANDOM % _total_videos + 1 ))" #  Aumentamos el intervalo de 0 a 1 
                                                             #+ como cota inferior.

while IFS='|'; read title url || [[ -n $title && -n $url ]]  #  Separamos según
                                                             #+ el caracter "|".
do
    mpv "$url" --title="$title"  #  Esto pone el título de la ventana
                                 #+ con el nombre del título del video.
    echo "Esto fue \"$title\" con la dirección \"$url\""
done <<< "$( sed -n "${_random_choice}p" < $_videos_db )"  # Hacemos uso de la elección aleatoria.
```

Y entonces tienes una estructura de archivos de la siguiente manera.

```
proyecto/
    |
    |___ programa.sh
    |___ videos.txt
```

De esta manera, separando los archivos, ya no tienes que editar tu archivo de código cada que quieras agregar o cambiar un vídeo, simplemente modifica tu pequeña base de datos en el archivo `videos.txt`. El defecto de esta sugerencia es con títulos que tengan el caracter `|` en el título, eso se podría solucionar cambiando el orden del vídeo y el título para después aplicar una expresión regular o hacer uso de `awk` o cambiando el separador a otro caracter menos usado.

PD. Ese ejemplo es totalmente funcional.

Comment: Me interesa tu solución... justamente acabo de hacer una pregunta por el problema de estar agregando link por link... No me podrías echar una manita? Adaptando tu código al mío? Toda la información esta en este nuevo post:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281599/como-puedo-dar-a-una-variable-valores-de-un-archivo-de-texto-bash  Gracias!

Comment: Claro, le daré una revisada, si te gustó mi respuesta, no olvides otorgarle una puntuación positiva.

Comment: buena respuesta! Leyendo desde archivo todo es más fácil, bien pensado