# ¿Como puedo dar a una variable valores desde un archivo de texto?

Tags: bash, variables, shell

Tengo otra duda referente a mi proyecto en bash...

Para que mi programa funcione necesito proporcionarle a una variable varios links de páginas web (en este caso youtube, es un reproductor)...
El problema es que es muy sucio que tenga que agregar todos los links de esta forma:

```
#Variable a la que tengo que asignar los valores en forma de link
items=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y")

#Variable "Size", la uso para contar la cantidad de links 
size=${#items[@]}
randomindex=$(($RANDOM % $size))

mpv ${items[$randomindex]}
```

Lo que deseo es poder extraer todos los links de un **archivo de texto** y que el código los pueda leer directamente de el archivo (valga me la redundancia).
El problema es que como podrán ver la variable **"size"** la uso para contar la cantidad de links que tiene y así con la variable **"randomindex"** poder crear una aleatoriedad **"${items[$randomindex]}"** y no estoy seguro de si seguirá funcionando igual si los extraigo de un archivo de texto... ¿Qué me recomiendan? Gracias!!!

PD: para leer los nombres de las canciones utilizo esto:

```
CANCION=${items[$randomindex]}

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs" ]
then
    echo "The Less i Know the Better - Tame Impala"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Como mencioné en mi respuesta a tu antigua [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280869/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-un-diccionario-asociativo-en-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1), puedes usar el código proporcionado ahí y se respetará lo aleatorio, y para contar los videos con `wc -l <el archivo>`.

El archivo tiene el formato.

```
título1|url1
titulo2|url2
...
```

El ejemplo en esa pregunta es funcional. Puedes copiarlo, pegarlo y ejecutarlo junto con tu archivo de `videos.txt` con el formato indicado.

Comment: Perdón por molestar...

Comment: Pero sinceramente no tengo mucha idea de como lo podría adaptar... crees que me puedas ayudar?

Comment: Copiálo, pégalo, ejecútalo, experimenta y escribes tus dudas. Es mejor si experimentas a si uno te hace el trabajo, sobretodo con `bash`, que es impresionante.

Answer (score 0):

Con esto:

```
items=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y")
```

estás definiendo un `array` de `bash` con una serie de elementos "duros" en el script, lo que puedes hacer, es definir este mismo `array` pero leyendo los valores desde una archivo de texto. Supongamos que tuvieras un archivo `urls.txt` con este contenido:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y
```

Para "llenar" el `array` en `bash`, la forma más compatible con las distintas versiones  sería hacer algo así:

```
items=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  items+=("$line")
done < urls.txt
```

**Importante**: cada línea debe tener un salto `\n`, incluso la última línea, si no, ésta no será considerada.

Una vez completo el array tu script solo debe hacer lo mismo que está haciendo ahora.

Fuente: [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)

Comment: ¿Qué tal así? `declare -a urls=( $(< urls.txt) )`

Comment: Si, @Cuauhtli, es posible y más compacto hacerlo también así, pero no es la forma recomendada: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207. Esta forma no considera la línea completa si esta tuviera un espacio.